# Unable to free the keyboard irq line: Device or resource busy

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt-handling

I was writing a sample request_irq code

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
int irq = 1;
int dev = 0xaa;

static irqreturn_t keyboard_handler(int irq, void *dev)
{
    static int counter = 0;
    pr_info("Keyboard Counter:%d\n", counter++);
    return IRQ_NONE;
}

static int test_interrupt_init(void)
{
    pr_info("%s: In init\n", __func__);
    return request_irq(irq, keyboard_handler, IRQF_SHARED,
            "my_keyboard_handler", &dev);
}

static void test_interrupt_exit(void)
{
    pr_info("%s: In exit\n", __func__);
    synchronize_irq(irq);
    free_irq(irq, &dev);
}

module_init(test_interrupt_init);
module_exit(test_interrupt_exit);
```

While removing this module, I am getting the error:

```
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:769 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'interrupt': Device or resource busy
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove module interrupt: Device or resource busy
```

Why I am getting this error, as I am using IRQF_SHARED and passed the dev parameter in request_irq and free_irq

Update: From the dmesg, I don't see any printk on rmmod
Added dmesg logs:

```
[ 4007.223281] Keyboard Counter:884
[ 4007.560846] Keyboard Counter:885
[ 4007.670339] Keyboard Counter:886
[ 4008.240139] Keyboard Counter:887
[ 4008.275412] Keyboard Counter:888
[ 4008.359338] Keyboard Counter:889
[ 4008.425101] Keyboard Counter:890
[ 4008.433026] Keyboard Counter:891
[ 4008.501763] Keyboard Counter:892
[ 4008.579201] Keyboard Counter:893
[ 4008.653335] Keyboard Counter:894
[ 4008.682862] Keyboard Counter:895
[ 4008.733950] Keyboard Counter:896

$ cat /proc/interrupts 
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
  0:          1          0          0          0   IO-APIC   2-edge      timer
  1:        449          0          0        707   IO-APIC   1-edge      i8042, my_keyboard_handler
  6:          0          0          2          0   IO-APIC   6-edge      floppy
  7:          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC   7-edge      parport0
  8:          0          1          0          0   IO-APIC   8-edge      rtc0
  9:          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC   9-fasteoi   acpi
```

Comment: what `cat /proc/modules` says about `interrupt` ? It should be in `Live` state. Can you show us `dmesg` logs ?

Comment: Added dmesg logs and cat /proc/interrupts output

Comment: Does this `interrupt` module referenced by any other module ? that's the probable reason for _Device or resource busy_. Meanwhile you can do `rmmod -f` to remove it, clear the `dmesg` and run again.

Comment: rmmod -f also gives the same error

Comment: Most likely the keyboard is already claimed by console or X not shared. You need to either be first or disable those.

Comment: The code you posted seems to work as expected on ubuntu 16.04 running `4.15.0-42-generic`

Comment: can you post the output of `lsmod | grep <your module>`

Comment: How did you come up with 1 as a parameter to *request_irq()*? Do you understand the difference between **hardware** IRQ and **linux** IRQ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`static int irq = 1, dev = 0xaa;`

You need to give permission to variable `irq`  and  then call `module_param()` like below

`module_param(irq, int, S_IRUGO);`

**sample code**

```
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
static int irq = 1,  dev = 0xaa, counter = 0;
module_param(irq, int, S_IRUGO); /* give the permission to user space variable */

static irqreturn_t keyboard_handler(int irq, void *dev)
{
        pr_info("Keyboard Counter:%d\n", counter++);
        return IRQ_NONE;
}
/* registering irq */
static int test_interrupt_init(void)
{
        pr_info("%s: In init\n", __func__);
        if(request_irq(irq, keyboard_handler, IRQF_SHARED,"my_keyboard_handler", &dev)) {
                return -1;
        }
        else
        {
                pr_info("success \n");
                return 0;
        }
}

static void test_interrupt_exit(void)
{
        pr_info("%s: In exit\n", __func__);
        synchronize_irq(irq); /* synchronize interrupt */
        free_irq(irq, &dev);
}

module_init(test_interrupt_init);
module_exit(test_interrupt_exit);
```

Comment: Yes it's working on my system. Can you tell your system kernel configuration ?

Comment: Linux ubuntu 4.20.0-rc6+ #1 SMP Fri Dec 28 00:44:41 PST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I copied your code and still the same issue: Device or resource busy

Comment: Same comment as per OP’s post.